# Why there is no assets/images directory in Rails 4.0 RC1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I just discovered that there isnt a default directory `assets/images` when I generate a Rails 4 app (Rails 4 rc1 currently). Whereas in Rails 3.1/3.2 its generated. Please tell me why is that so? I mean I can create a directory in a second, but thats not the point. If I didnt get the reason for this on any announcement I am sorry, otherwise it makes no sense to me. Thank you

Comment: Is the `rails.png` in the `public` directory when you generate the application.

Comment: I dont have a `rails.png` in my public folder. Its a default created `rails new myapp` with rails4rc on my localhost.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how exactly to include a few small images (like a logo) into a rails 4 application.  How were you able to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 image directory not present in assets anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842279/rails-4-image-directory-not-present-in-assets-anymore)

Answer (score 1):

Just found out myself that there's no index.html in public any more either because it's done dynamically in Rails 4 there's no image anymore, so the directory might not get generated any longer [generate 'app/assets/images' directory when creating new rails app](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10436)