# Rails 4 image directory not present in assets anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

When creating a new Rails 4 project, I have `javascripts` and `stylesheets` directories inside the `app/assets` folder, but I no longer see the `images` directory. Are we supposed to be putting our images in another folder?

***UPDATE***: I created an `images` directory in the `assets` folder. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. If I try to load an image with `<img src="/assets/my_image.jpg"/>`, it can't be found. Seems like I need to somehow enable my `images` directory?

Comment: This is a duplicate question that got answered today - [Why there is no assets/images directory in Rails 4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835892/why-there-is-no-assets-images-directory-in-rails-4/16836262#16836262

Comment: @David - that link didn't answer the question...

Comment: you are required to create the `assets/images` folder as rails 4 does not generate for you

Comment: @David - I updated my description, simply creating the `images` directory doesn't work.

Comment: Did you restart your rails server after adding the directory?

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci - NO, didn't think about that!

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci - unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: no @lflores I never did find the solution

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4.* now have images folder under app/assets/images/

JS/CSS/IMAGES are now part of the rails app, in previous you might put them under public folder, [further reading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and have reached at least a temporary solution.  I haven't figured out all the little details yet but here is one thing I have discovered.

1. Rails 4.0.0 (released today, June 25th) has an assets/images directory when you create a new app whereas rails 4.0.0.RC2 didn't - you had to create one and for some odd reason even then images weren't rendering for me.

I updated my rails 4.0.0.RC2 app to rails 4.0.0 but still had problems with images.  However, when I created a new rails 4 app the images rendered just fine.  As I searched all over for a solution to the image problem I noticed @at. posted a number of different SO posts about this same issue.  I wanted to let you know what I found.  I'll update when I find out more.

Answer (score 0):

What is your server log saying? I had an issue with calling image URLs inside resource views.

First, maybe try `<%= image_tag "image.png" %>`

If you don't want to use `image_tag`, play with the leading `/` - depending on where you call the image, Rails may prepend a resource onto the request, so `assets/image.png` called from a `user` view may request `/users/image.png`, whereas `/assets/image.png` may render the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i just tried creating a images directory under public and put in my images into that directory and tried on localhost and it works =). Hope it helps u guys too. My rails version = 4.0.0 rc2

This is the code in my particular directory where i want my image to appear on ( for eg: the homepage - welcome/index.rb )

## Index.rb

....
...

```
<img src= "/images/DNA_side.jpg" width="180" height="500" align="left"/ >
```

....

Comment: If you put images inside public directory, it'd work, but you won't get the asset pipeline benefits.

Comment: Kazim : I read bout it but i still can't really see why do we need asset. Sorry i'm quite new to rails too... Still learning it due to my project is using Rails. ( currently in development phase) having problem with production part... whenever i upload my files to the server they can't seem to read ruby codes... no idea why

Comment: Asset Pipeline is used for efficiently deploying assets (to CDN or otherwise), compressing JS and CSS, invalidating old files when they change etc. Read about it at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this

image_tag('assets/images/logo.gif), :class=> 'logo-main another-class', :alt => 'my company main logo'

hope this work for you

Answer (score 0):

Move your /images directory from assets into the /public directory and it will work :)